# OpenCV 3 doesn't seem to work with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, windows-8.1

I followed [this tutorial](https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/qt-5-3-1-64-bit-mingw-windows/) to install OpenCV to work with Qt.
I used OpenCV with Qt before, a couple of years ago, and I had to build both OpenCV and Qt myself. I was now happy that a solution exists by building only OpenCV.

CMake, as usual, had a lot of errors. I had to disable a bunch of extras, like opencv_apps and examples, but then it built the libraries correctly.
The dynamic libs didn't work, but I planned to use it statically anyway.

After linking the OpenCV libraries in Qt, not forgetting that the opening of images has been moved to "imgcodecs"

```
LIBS += -lopencv_core300 -lopencv_highgui300 -lopencv_imgproc300
LIBS += -lopencv_imgcodecs300
```

I tried a simple program:

```
#include <opencv.hpp>

// ...

cv::Mat image = cv::imread("testimage.png");
cv::namedWindow("Test image");
cv::imshow("Test image", image);
cv::waitKey(1000);
```

It didn't work.

> matrix.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C1R@20'

Searching for "ippicviSum" on Google returns absolutely nothing (well, until this question will be crawled by them).

I know that the libraries at least somewhat work, or are at least **found**, because if I remove `lopencv_imgcodecs300` from the project file, I get an additional error, which wasn't there when the library was included:

> error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'

---

I gave up on the C++ API, and tried to use the classical C API. (In my trial 2 years ago, the C++ API also had some problems - the basic opening and displaying worked but the more complicated algorithms gave linker errors, so I resorted to the C API, which worked correctly)

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <cvwimage.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

// ...

IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("testimage.png");
```

The result:

> loadsave.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to
>   `cv::String::deallocate()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that OpenCV 3.0 is incompatible with the mingw version (491) shipped with Qt 5.4.

Upgrading to Qt 5.5, which uses mingw 492, solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

'ippicviSum_8u_C1R' is the intel performance primitives (ipp) library that now comes with opencv for free. It looks like you are missing the download, I normally build opencv from source but if you got an installer you might need to get the Intel library separately.

There is no need to use the cv::String type, just use regular std::string. The cv types are there to support old embedded platforms with obsolete c++ compilers. It is possible that some Qt macro is redefining "String" and breaking the code ?

edit: The problem might also be that you are using the legacy C api.
instead do:

`cv::Mat image = cv::imread("testimage.png");`

or  if you still have an issue,

`cv::Mat image = cv::imread(std::string("testimage.png"));`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out. I downloaded OpenCV as an installer from the official webpage, but as the binaries  didn't work with Qt and there was a source in the installation package, I used that source to build it.

Comment: About `cv::String` : how can I **not** use it? I didn't specifically include it, it seems that a simple string literal is being compiled as `cv::String`.

Comment: About your last edit: please look at my first example. I used the new API first, and only after it didn't work, did I try the C API. From prior experience it was always the C API which worked in situations where C++ API had problems.  (I'll try a source-only download and check whether that source is different from what is in the download containing the binaries, and if it is, then I'll rebuild it, when I'm again at the computer where I did the experiments)